# Wordpress WP_Query is slow

Tags: wordpress

I have a few REST Endpoints in my Wordpress-Site, but there is one WP_Query that is incredible slow (needs about 5000ms). I use this function to check if a Post already exists and when no I insert a new Post and when yes I update the post with the new data.

```
public static function findPostByInternId($post_type, $client, $intern_id) {
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        "post_type" => $post_type,
        "meta_query" => array(
            array(
                "key" => "intern_id",
                 "value" => $intern_id
            ),
            array(
                "key" => "client",
                "value" => $client
            )
     )
   )); ));

   return $query;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If there is a better solution or best practice to prevent 5000ms loading time....